# Does 「7分の1」 mean 1:7 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, words, mathematics

Found a sentence,

> 人間の身体能力は吸血鬼の**7分の1**しかありません

Is this how you write ratios in Japanese?

Comment: I think 1:7 is １対７. ７分の１ is 1/7.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly (as several have commented). This is how you talk about *fractions* in Japanese:

> 7分の1 → 1/7

Literally, you can think about it as 'one part of seven'. It is not a ratio, i.e. 'one part to seven parts', as that equates to 1/8.

Comment: This is correct. Ratio is 1:7, and fraction is 1/7 in Japanese _language_ (not mathematics).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> n / m = n : m

is written

> m分のn,

where "m" and "n" are positive integers.

BTW, is

> 人間の身体能力は、吸血鬼の身体能力の7分の1しかありません

more acceptable for you?

*** added  ***

I just learned that the notation n : m confuses some people.

Here is what Hans Lundmark pointed out to me in regard of the usage of n : m. I hope this helps to resolve their confusion.

> You have good historical reasons for interpreting n:m as n/m.
>
> From http://jeff560.tripod.com/operation.html:
>
> The colon (:) was used in 1633 in a text entitled Johnson Arithmetik; In two Bookes (2nd ed.: London, 1633). However Johnson only used the symbol to indicate fractions (for example three-fourths was written 3:4); he did not use the symbol for division "dissociated from the idea of a fraction" (Cajori vol. 1, page 276).
>
> Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz (1646-1716) used : for both ratio and division in 1684 in the Acta eruditorum (Cajori vol. 1, page 295).

As for the said excerpt, it reads "The (average?) physical ability of humankind is one-seventh of that of vampire."

***  added (again)  ***

In view of the *established* usage as described in http://www.bradford.ac.uk/wimba-files/msu-course/media/ratio%20teaching%20new.pdf , the assertion by @Earthliŋ

> n : m is usually the notation for "n parts in (n+m) parts vs. m parts in (n+m) parts", so 1:7 would correspond to 1/8 and 7/8

should read

> In the context that something is to be divided into n : m, it can be considered as "n parts in (n+m) parts vs. m parts in (n+m) parts", so 1:7 can be specified as the pair (1/8, 7/8) if needed.

Comment: No! `n : m` is usually the notation for "n parts in (n+m) parts vs. m parts in (n+m) parts", so 1:7 would correspond to 1/8 and 7/8.

Comment: @ Earthliŋ: Aren't you confusing part-to-oat ratio with part-to-whole ratio?

Comment: I don't think I am. Maybe the OP could clarify whether by 1:7 he meant 1/7.

Comment: @ Earthliŋ: You may want to have a look at this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio .

Comment: @ Earthliŋ: And this, too, may be of help -> http://www.bradford.ac.uk/wimba-files/msu-course/media/ratio%20teaching%20new.pdf  .

Comment: @Earthliŋ: In view of  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio and  bradford.ac.uk/wimba-files/msu-course/media/ , your <n : m is usually the notation for "n parts in (n+m) parts vs. m parts in (n+m) parts"> is *definitely* incorrect. That is, you are confusing part-to-part ratio with part-to-whole ratio.

Comment: Down voting as it is misleading and incorrect. they may be mathematically be the same (and I agree), but it also depends on where you come from. In Japan, we are taught they are different and read them differently. As @YangMuye wrote in the comment, we read 1:7 as １対７ and 1/7 as ７分の１.  Debating whether they mean the same is up to mathematics, but they do have differences when it comes to Japanese _language_. We do NOT write 1:7 to mean "one out of seven". We use it for "one versus seven".

Comment: I even remember my math teacher back in elementary school taught us 1:7 means division in some countries, but not in Japan.

Comment: @CookieMonster: <debating whether they mean the same is up to mathematics, but they do have difference when it comes to Japanese language> Are you sure what you are talking about? You have to read and understand this excerpt form wikipedia -> "Other uses for fractions are to represent ratios and to represent division. Thus the fraction 3/4 is also used to represent the ratio 3:4 (the ratio of the part to the whole) and the division 3 ÷ 4 (three divided by four)."

Comment: @eltonjon Yes, I'm certain. I completely agree with what you are saying in terms of mathematics, but we are talking about the language. ;) "One out of seven" and "one versus seven" may entail the same thing, but have different _meaning_.

Comment: @CookieMonster: I don't quite understand what you mean by "may mean the same, but have different meaning." Can you explain it in layman's language?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I corrected it. I meant that we use 1:7 and 1/7 in different context. We use 1:7 for _ratios_, and 1/7 is for _fractions_. If someone is talking about "one seventh" of something, and you write 1:7, some Japanese people will get confused.

Comment: @CookieMonster:　< If someone is talking about "one seventh" of something, and you write 1:7, some Japanese people will get confused> I don't get it. If X is "one seventh" of Y, it exactly means X : Y = 1 : 7, right?

Comment: Again, in mathematics yes, but not in Japanese _language_.

Comment: ＠@CookieMonster: <in mathematics yes, but not in Japanese language> That doesn't makes sense. Alright, If you want to continue like this, move on to "chat."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 「７分の１」 means same as 1:7 mathematically.

1:7 = (1/8):(7/8) = (1/8)/(7/8) = (1/8)x(8/7) = 8/56 = 1/7

However, in Japan, kids are taught that 1:7 is 「[比]{ひ}」 and 1/7 is 「[分数]{ぶんすう}」.  I guess that 「比」 is translated as "ratios", and 「分数」 is translated as "fractions" generally. So, Japanese people tend to think that 1/7 is not a ratio, maybe.

In English, both 1:7 and 1/7 can be read "one to seven", right? And both 1:7 and 1/7 are called "ratio" in some cases, maybe? (Sorry, if my knowledge about English is wrong.) But in Japanese, each of them has its own way to be read.

> 1:7 is read 「[１]{いち}[対]{たい}[７]{なな}」.

> 1/7 is read 「[７]{なな}[分]{ぶん}の[１]{いち}」.

There are other ways to express proportions in Japanese. For example,

> 1/10 is read 「[１]{いち}[割]{わり}」 ＝ 10%
>
> 2/10 is read 「[２]{に}[割]{わり}」 ＝ 20%

Which word should be used is up to the situation and context.

If your "ratio" means both 1:7 and 1/7, I would answer that there are several ways to write ratio in Japanese, and 「７分の１」 is one of them. So, yes.